# How to require a generic type argument in a genric type type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type RetuType<T> = () => T
type RetuGeneric<T, G> = () => G<T>

const f: RetuType<number> = () => 114514 // OK
const g: RetuGeneric<number, RetuType> = () => 114514 // Error: Type `G` is not genric.
```

Another example
In fact I'm working on a mixin type.

```
type Ctor<T = object> = new (...arg: any[]) => T
type Mixin<I, S> = <T> (B: Ctor<T>) => Ctor<I> & S<I>
// I and S stand for instance type and static type.
```

How to write a proper `RetuGeneric`?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that you can't. I'm not sure why you would want to... `RetuGeneric<number, RetuType>` is more verbose than simply typing `RetuType<number>`...

Comment: @jered edited. I want `S` to be a genric type because `fromXYZ` static methods return a instance of the class.

Comment: @ForkΨKillet the term for the thing you're trying to do is "Higher kinded types". Unfortunately, typescript does not support it. Here's the long-running github thread on the topic: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213